# Get files contained in a mega.nz folder (Python 3.10)

Tags: python

I need to retrieve the files contained in the MEGAsync folder of the Mega.nz service. I have been trying to do it for almost a week without success using the mega.py module. I have tried both with email and password, as well as with the public link of the folder. I have tried every example I found online (including those on Stack Overflow), but they all have thrown errors of various kinds. From non-existent methods to non-existent dictionary elements. It's as if the examples I found were from an old version of the module or something like that.

```
    from mega import Mega
    mega = Mega()
    m = mega.login('example@example.com', 'example123')

    # Get 'MEGAsync' folder
    folder_name = 'MEGAsync'
    folder = m.find(folder_name)

    # Get the file list inside the folder
    files = m.get_files_in_node(folder[0])

    # Print file names on the list
    for f in files:
        print(f['name'])
```

Error:

```
    print(f['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

In fact, in the dictionary 'files' obtained, it does not contain any names of the files contained in the MEGAsync folder

Can anyone give me the example of a code that really works?

Comment: I think you're expecting `f` to be some kind of structure, but apparently it's just a string.